# Class 'Database' not found (need a little help here)

Tags: php, database

I am releatively new to PHP and having read previous answers to this questions I am completely confused..

I have recently moved an old website onto a new server host and when trying to load the page I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'database' not found in /home4/courseso/public_html/plugins/system/legacy.php on line 147
```

I am very confused as to what this means or is refering too, all I see on my page is a blank white background and that is it... the legacy.php file is as follows.

```
<?php
/**
* @version      $Id: legacy.php 11299 2008-11-22 01:40:44Z ian $
* @package      Joomla
* @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
* @license      GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
* Joomla! is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* See COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
*/

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

/**
 * Joomla! Debug plugin
 *
 * @package     Joomla
 * @subpackage  System
 */
class  plgSystemLegacy extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * For php4 compatability we must not use the __constructor as a constructor for plugins
     * because func_get_args ( void ) returns a copy of all passed arguments NOT references.
     * This causes problems with cross-referencing necessary for the observer design pattern.
     *
     * @param   object      $subject The object to observe
      * @param  array       $config  An array that holds the plugin configuration
     * @since   1.0
     */
    function plgSystemLegacy(& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);

        global $mainframe;

        // Define the 1.0 legacy mode constant
        define('_JLEGACY', '1.0');

        // Set global configuration var for legacy mode
        $config = &JFactory::getConfig();
        $config->setValue('config.legacy', 0);

        // Import library dependencies
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'classes.php');
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'functions.php');

        // Register legacy classes for autoloading
        JLoader::register('mosAdminMenus'   , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'adminmenus.php');
        JLoader::register('mosCache'        , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'cache.php');
        JLoader::register('mosCategory'     , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'category.php');
        JLoader::register('mosCommonHTML'   , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'commonhtml.php');
        JLoader::register('mosComponent'    , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'component.php');
        JLoader::register('mosContent'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'content.php');
        JLoader::register('mosDBTable'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'dbtable.php');
        JLoader::register('mosHTML'         , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'html.php');
        JLoader::register('mosInstaller'    , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'installer.php');
        JLoader::register('mosMainFrame'    , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'mainframe.php');
        JLoader::register('mosMambot'       , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'mambot.php');
        JLoader::register('mosMambotHandler', dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'mambothandler.php');
        JLoader::register('mosMenu'         , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'menu.php');
        JLoader::register('mosMenuBar'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'menubar.php');
        JLoader::register('mosModule'       , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'module.php');
        //JLoader::register('mosPageNav'    , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'pagination.php');
        JLoader::register('mosParameters'   , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'parameters.php');
        JLoader::register('patFactory'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'patfactory.php');
        JLoader::register('mosProfiler'     , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'profiler.php');
        JLoader::register('mosSection'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'section.php');
        JLoader::register('mosSession'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'session.php');
        JLoader::register('mosToolbar'      , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'toolbar.php');
        JLoader::register('mosUser'         , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.'user.php');

        // Register class for the database, depends on which db type has been selected for use
        $dbtype = $config->getValue('config.dbtype', 'mysql');
        JLoader::register('database'        , dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.$dbtype.'.php');

        /**
         * Legacy define, _ISO define not used anymore. All output is forced as utf-8.
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        define('_ISO','charset=utf-8');

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use _JEXEC instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use _JEXEC instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        define( '_MOS_MAMBO_INCLUDED', 1 );

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use DATE_FORMAT_LC instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        DEFINE('_DATE_FORMAT_LC', JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC1') ); //Uses PHP's strftime Command Format

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use DATE_FORMAT_LC2 instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        DEFINE('_DATE_FORMAT_LC2', JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'));

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use JFilterInput instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        DEFINE( "_MOS_NOTRIM", 0x0001 );

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use JFilterInput instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        DEFINE( "_MOS_ALLOWHTML", 0x0002 );

        /**
         * Legacy constant, use JFilterInput instead
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        DEFINE( "_MOS_ALLOWRAW", 0x0004 );

        /**
         * Legacy global, use JVersion->getLongVersion() instead
         * @name $_VERSION
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
         $GLOBALS['_VERSION']   = new JVersion();
         $version               = $GLOBALS['_VERSION']->getLongVersion();

        /**
         * Legacy global, use JFactory::getDBO() instead
         * @name $database
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        $conf =& JFactory::getConfig();
        $GLOBALS['database'] = new database($conf->getValue('config.host'), $conf->getValue('config.user'), $conf->getValue('config.password'), $conf->getValue('config.db'), $conf->getValue('config.dbprefix'));
        $GLOBALS['database']->debug($conf->getValue('config.debug'));

        /**
         * Legacy global, use JFactory::getUser() [JUser object] instead
         * @name $my
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        $user   =& JFactory::getUser();

        $GLOBALS['my']      = (object)$user->getProperties();
        $GLOBALS['my']->gid = $user->get('aid', 0);

        /**
         * Insert configuration values into global scope (for backwards compatibility)
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */

        $temp = new JConfig;
        foreach (get_object_vars($temp) as $k => $v) {
            $name = 'mosConfig_'.$k;
            $GLOBALS[$name] = $v;
        }

        $GLOBALS['mosConfig_live_site']     = substr_replace(JURI::root(), '', -1, 1);
        $GLOBALS['mosConfig_absolute_path'] = JPATH_SITE;
        $GLOBALS['mosConfig_cachepath'] = JPATH_BASE.DS.'cache';

        $GLOBALS['mosConfig_offset_user']   = 0;

        $lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
        $GLOBALS['mosConfig_lang']          = $lang->getBackwardLang();

        $config->setValue('config.live_site',       $GLOBALS['mosConfig_live_site']);
        $config->setValue('config.absolute_path',   $GLOBALS['mosConfig_absolute_path']);
        $config->setValue('config.lang',            $GLOBALS['mosConfig_lang']);

        /**
         * Legacy global, use JFactory::getUser() instead
         * @name $acl
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        $acl =& JFactory::getACL();

        // Legacy ACL's for backward compat
        $acl->addACL( 'administration', 'edit', 'users', 'super administrator', 'components', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'administration', 'edit', 'users', 'administrator', 'components', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'administration', 'edit', 'users', 'super administrator', 'user properties', 'block_user' );
        $acl->addACL( 'administration', 'manage', 'users', 'super administrator', 'components', 'com_users' );
        $acl->addACL( 'administration', 'manage', 'users', 'administrator', 'components', 'com_users' );
        $acl->addACL( 'administration', 'config', 'users', 'super administrator' );
        //$acl->addACL( 'administration', 'config', 'users', 'administrator' );

        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'add', 'users', 'author', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'add', 'users', 'editor', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'add', 'users', 'publisher', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'edit', 'users', 'author', 'content', 'own' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'edit', 'users', 'editor', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'edit', 'users', 'publisher', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'publish', 'users', 'publisher', 'content', 'all' );

        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'add', 'users', 'manager', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'edit', 'users', 'manager', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'publish', 'users', 'manager', 'content', 'all' );

        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'add', 'users', 'administrator', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'edit', 'users', 'administrator', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'publish', 'users', 'administrator', 'content', 'all' );

        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'add', 'users', 'super administrator', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'edit', 'users', 'super administrator', 'content', 'all' );
        $acl->addACL( 'action', 'publish', 'users', 'super administrator', 'content', 'all' );

        $acl->addACL( 'com_syndicate', 'manage', 'users', 'super administrator' );
        $acl->addACL( 'com_syndicate', 'manage', 'users', 'administrator' );
        $acl->addACL( 'com_syndicate', 'manage', 'users', 'manager' );

        $GLOBALS['acl'] =& $acl;

        /**
         * Legacy global
         * @name $task
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        $GLOBALS['task'] = JRequest::getString('task');

        /**
         * Load the site language file (the old way - to be deprecated)
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        global $mosConfig_lang;
        $mosConfig_lang = JFilterInput::clean($mosConfig_lang, 'cmd');
        $file = JPATH_SITE.DS.'language'.DS.$mosConfig_lang.'.php';
        if (file_exists( $file )) {
            require_once( $file);
        } else {
            $file = JPATH_SITE.DS.'language'.DS.'english.php';
            if (file_exists( $file )) {
                require_once( $file );
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Legacy global
         *  use JApplicaiton->registerEvent and JApplication->triggerEvent for event handling
         *  use JPlugingHelper::importPlugin to load bot code
         *  @deprecated As of version 1.5
         */
        $GLOBALS['_MAMBOTS'] = new mosMambotHandler();

        $mosmsg = JRequest::getVar( 'mosmsg' );
        $mainframe->enqueueMessage( $mosmsg );
    }

    /**
     * Fixes the $my global if the user was restored by the remember me plugin
     */
    function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        $user   =& JFactory::getUser();
        if ($user->id) {
            if ($GLOBALS['my']->id === 0) {
                $GLOBALS['my']  = (object)$user->getProperties();
                $GLOBALS['my']->gid = $user->get('aid', 0);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }



    function onAfterRoute()
    {
        global $mainframe;
        if ($mainframe->isAdmin()) {
            return;
        }

        switch(JRequest::getCmd('option'))
        {
            case 'com_content'   :
                $this->routeContent();
                break;
            case 'com_newsfeeds' :
                $this->routeNewsfeeds();
                break;
            case 'com_weblinks' :
                $this->routeWeblinks();
                break;
            case 'com_frontpage' :
                JRequest::setVar('option', 'com_content');
                JRequest::setVar('view', 'frontpage');
                break;
            case 'com_login'     :
                JRequest::setVar('option', 'com_user');
                JRequest::setVar('view', 'login');
                break;
            case 'com_registration'     :
                JRequest::setVar('option', 'com_user');
                JRequest::setVar('view', 'register');
                break;
        }

        /**
         * Legacy global, use JApplication::getTemplate() instead
         * @name $cur_template
         * @deprecated  As of version 1.5
         */
        $GLOBALS['cur_template'] = $mainframe->getTemplate();
    }

    function routeContent()
    {
        $viewName   = JRequest::getCmd( 'view', 'article' );
        $layout     = JRequest::getCmd( 'layout', 'default' );

        // interceptors to support legacy urls
        switch( JRequest::getCmd('task'))
        {
            //index.php?option=com_content&task=x&id=x&Itemid=x
            case 'blogsection':
                $viewName   = 'section';
                $layout = 'blog';
                break;
            case 'section':
                $viewName   = 'section';
                break;
            case 'category':
                $viewName   = 'category';
                break;
            case 'blogcategory':
                $viewName   = 'category';
                $layout = 'blog';
                break;
            case 'archivesection':
            case 'archivecategory':
                $viewName   = 'archive';
                break;
            case 'frontpage' :
                $viewName = 'frontpage';
                break;
            case 'view':
                $viewName   = 'article';
                break;
        }

        JRequest::setVar('layout', $layout);
        JRequest::setVar('view', $viewName);
    }

    function routeNewsfeeds()
    {
        $viewName = JRequest::getCmd( 'view', 'categories' );

        // interceptors to support legacy urls
        switch( JRequest::getCmd('task'))
        {
            //index.php?option=com_newsfeeds&task=x&catid=xid=x&Itemid=x
            case 'view':
                $viewName   = 'newsfeed';
                break;

            default:
            {
                if(JRequest::getInt('catid') && !JRequest::getCmd('view')) {
                    $viewName = 'category';
                }
            }
        }

        JRequest::setVar('view', $viewName);
    }

    function routeWeblinks()
    {
        $viewName = JRequest::getCmd( 'view', 'categories' );

        // interceptors to support legacy urls
        switch( JRequest::getCmd('task'))
        {
            //index.php?option=com_weblinks&task=x&catid=xid=x
            case 'view':
                $viewName   = 'weblink';
                break;

            default:
            {
                if(($catid = JRequest::getInt('catid')) && !JRequest::getCmd('view')) {
                    $viewName = 'category';
                    JRequest::setVar('id', $catid);
                }
            }
        }

        JRequest::setVar('view', $viewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post line 147 and maybe some code surrounding it? StackOverflow does not provide line numbers and I'm too lazy to count them manually or sift through that huge block of code. edit: nvm, I'll just paste it in a text editor

Comment: $conf =& JFactory::getConfig();
  $GLOBALS['database'] = new database($conf->getValue('config.host'), $conf->getValue('config.user'), $conf->getValue('config.password'), $conf->getValue('config.db'), $conf->getValue('config.dbprefix'));
  $GLOBALS['database']->debug($conf->getValue('config.debug'));

Answer (score 0):

I am no Joomla expert, but it looks like your problem is in the lines:

```
$dbtype = $config->getValue('config.dbtype', 'mysql');
JLoader::register('database', dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.$dbtype.'.php');
```

Perhaps you should do a:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__).DS.'legacy'.DS.$dbtype.'.php';
```

And investigate that file (make sure it exists, etc)

Comment: I get more errors when I add 'echo' infront of dirname... it doesn't even process